# How to change the color of the wrapper with the background of the bordering element, the border color

Tags: html, css

I have code like this.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper>div {
  min-width: calc(300px/3);
}

.child1 {
  background: blue;
}

div.child2 {
  background: green;
  min-width: calc(300px - 300px/3);
}

div.child3 {
  background: yellow;
  min-width: calc(300px - 300px/2);
}

div.child4 {
  background: purple;
  border: 4px gold dashed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: calc(300px - 300px/2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
  </div>
  <div class="child4">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to override the flex container border of the flex child element with the border and background-color bordering the flex container.

Also, when a dotted line such as dash is used for the border here, I want to show the border of the flex container transparent below the dotted line.

[image: What I want to achieve image]

I thought negative margin was the only way to do this, but it didn't work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper>div {
  min-width: calc(300px/3);
}

.child1 {
  background: blue;
    margin-left: -3px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

div.child2 {
  background: green;
  min-width: calc(300px - 300px/3);
}

div.child3 {
  background: yellow;
  min-width: calc(300px - 300px/2);
}

div.child4 {
  background: purple;
  border: 4px gold dashed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: calc(300px - 300px/2);
  margin-right: -3px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
  </div>
  <div class="child4">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**This code may help you to solve your problem. you can play with z-index property.**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  border:4px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  z-index:4;
}

.wrapper>div {
}

.child1 {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

div.child2 {
  background: green;
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

div.child3 {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  position:relative;
  z-index:3;
}

div.child4 {
  background: purple;
  border: 4px gold dashed;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
  </div>
  <div class="child4">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```